# Is $(n\alpha_1, n^2 \alpha_2)$ uniformly distributed on $[0,1)^2$

Tags: dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

I have a question

If $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ are both irrationals then is $(n\alpha_1, n^2 \alpha_2)$ uniformly distributed on $[0,1)^2$?

I'm trying to use the Weyl's theorem and Fourier series. But I don't know how to do..
Anyone can help me?

Comment: Also I'm trying to connect this problem to uniquely ergodic system but it does not also give me an answer...

Comment: You can consider the map $T:\mathbb{T}\to\mathbb{T}$ with $T(x,y,z)=(x+\alpha_1,y+\alpha_2,z+2y+\alpha_2)$.